# error 500 when I copy my data with heroku

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, heroku, strapi

I am updating my plan from a hobby dev to a hobby basic

I follow the step for doing this according to the doc (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrading-with-pg-copy-2-enter-maintenance-mode-to-prevent-database-writes)

So I created a new database with the hobby basics plan

Then I put my app into maintenance by running "heroku maintenance:on"

At this point my app is on maintenance

But now I would like to copy my data from my previous database
So I tried several command :

```
heroku pg:copy HEROKU_DATABASE HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW_URL --app myAppName

heroku pg:copy DATABASE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW_URL --app myAppName

heroku pg:copy HEROKU_DATABASE HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW --app myAppName

heroku pg:copy DATABASE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW --app myAppName
```

but anytime the response is this :

Starting copy of HEROKU_DATABASE to YELLOW... !
▸ Expected response to be successful, got 500

What can I do to copy my data to my new database ?

notice that it is a Strapi node js app which is running

Comment: notice that I have my images on amazon S3 (I don't know if there is a link)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I had 2 databases url associated to one database (DATABASE_URL & HEROKU_DATABASE_URL), so I promote against the first database so handle the issue and then I could copy the data with pg:copy